# Do Java enums allocate heap memory in the Android Runtime?

Tags: java, android, memory, enums, heap-memory

I was watching a video by two Android engineers talking about garbage collection in Android. In the introduction they do a little banter over enums. Romain Guy says: "I have to correct you there. Enums, they don't allocate. That's the whole point." At first, I that Romain just made a joke because enums work like this in other languages. But after this, Chet seems to concede that enums indeed to not allocate, but doing some "memory-related" stuff (implying: living on the stack). This reaction is what confuses me.

https://youtu.be/Zc4JP8kNGmQ?t=96

In my understanding, enums in Java are basically fixed collections of class-instances and [seeing as `Enum` implements `Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) as good as object instantiations from a memory perspective, and so will be allocated to the heap.

But I can imagine that enums have some special status, owing to the strong properties the compiler can draw about them. Analogously, I know there are various optimizations for `String` like a shared pool for literals.

I am currently in the situation where I have fixed list of objects that I use as constants in my application. So I can implement this as an enum or as an array of class instantiations. Assuming readability is not an issue, would it be more performant to do the former?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enums are objects. Like all objects, they live on the heap.

Indeed, if you decompile a simple enum, like:

```
enum Foo { A, B }
```

it looks like this (some stuff omitted):

```
  static {};
    Code:
       0: new           #4                  // class Foo
       3: dup
       4: ldc           #7                  // String A
       6: iconst_0
       7: invokespecial #8                  // Method "<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
      10: putstatic     #9                  // Field A:LFoo;
      13: new           #4                  // class Foo
      16: dup
      17: ldc           #10                 // String B
      19: iconst_1
      20: invokespecial #8                  // Method "<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
      23: putstatic     #11                 // Field B:LFoo;
      26: iconst_2
      27: anewarray     #4                  // class Foo
      30: dup
      31: iconst_0
      32: getstatic     #9                  // Field A:LFoo;
      35: aastore
      36: dup
      37: iconst_1
      38: getstatic     #11                 // Field B:LFoo;
      41: aastore
      42: putstatic     #1                  // Field $VALUES:[LFoo;
      45: return
```

which is basically the same as a class like this:

```
class Bar {
  static final Bar A = new Bar("A");
  static final Bar B = new Bar("B");

  static final Bar[] $VALUES;

  static {
    Bar[] array = new Bar[2];
    array[0] = A;
    array[1] = B;
    $VALUES = array;
  }

  private Bar(String name) {}
}
```

which decompiles to:

```
  static {};
    Code:
       0: new           #2                  // class Bar
       3: dup
       4: ldc           #3                  // String A
       6: invokespecial #4                  // Method "<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
       9: putstatic     #5                  // Field A:LBar;
      12: new           #2                  // class Bar
      15: dup
      16: ldc           #6                  // String B
      18: invokespecial #4                  // Method "<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      21: putstatic     #7                  // Field B:LBar;
      24: iconst_2
      25: anewarray     #2                  // class Bar
      28: astore_0
      29: aload_0
      30: iconst_0
      31: getstatic     #5                  // Field A:LBar;
      34: aastore
      35: aload_0
      36: iconst_1
      37: getstatic     #7                  // Field B:LBar;
      40: aastore
      41: aload_0
      42: putstatic     #8                  // Field $VALUES:[LBar;
      45: return
```

There are a few other special things you get from an enum (like guarantees that they can't be creayed reflectively); but really, they are just regular objects.

The point that I think they are trying to make is that enums don't get allocated more than once (they are a good way to implement singetons, if you really need a singleton). So, you pay a small, fixed cost to load the enum class; but you can then reuse those same instances over and over.

Comment: Thanks! The only caveat maybe is that `values()` clones the array every time, which I guess _does_ allocate a new array every time.